# What is the limit $\lim_ {n\to\infty} \frac {3^n} {n^n}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know intuitively that it should be zero since n^n grows faster than 3^n but I get infinity.
Here is my work.

$\ln(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(\frac{3^n}{n^n})$

$\ln(y) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n \ln(\frac{3}{n}) $

$\ln(y) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n [\ln(3) - \ln(n)] $

$\ln(y) = \lim_{n\to\infty}  [\ln(3) - \ln(n)]/n^{-1} $

using L'Hopitals Rule, I have

$\ln(y) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{-1/n}{-n^{-2}} $

$\ln(y) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n = \infty$

$y = e^{\infty} = \infty $

where is my mistake?

Comment: You used Lhopital's rule, but $\ln 3 - \ln n\to -\infty$ and $n^{-1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Not worth more than a comment, but what is your need for complicated theorems like L'Hopital in the first place? (That's an actual question, not a snide remark.) Note that for $n \geq 4$, you have $0 \leq \frac{3^n}{n^n} \leq \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$: the Squeeze theorem is enough.

Comment: isn' $$\lim_{n\to\infty}3^n = \infty$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^n = \infty$$, the use of L'Hopitals Rule valid?

Comment: You're also trying to take $\log(0)$ in your very first line, which I would be wary of.

Comment: @017 After taking the logarithm, you have $\ln(3/n)$ in the numerator and $1/n$ in the denominator. The former goes to $-\infty$, the latter to $0$.

Comment: Why not simply observe that $(3/n)^n<3/n$ for $n>3$?

Answer (score 4):

You wrongly used Lhopital's rule, because $\ln 3 - \ln n\to -\infty$ and $n^{-1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Not using L'Hopital's rule,
$$0\le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{n^n} \le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{4^{n-1}}=0$$
by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

let $y = \left(\frac 3 n\right)^n.$ then $$\ln y = n (\ln(3) - \ln(n))\to -\infty \text{ as } n \to \infty.  $$ that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} y = e^{ln y} = e^{-\infty} = 0. $

Comment: ah!  I see.  So my mistake was in applying L'Hopitals Rule to a determinate form, right?  This would explain why I got the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the root test to the series $\sum \dfrac {3^n} {n^n}$:
$$
\lim_ {n\to\infty} \left(\frac {3^n} {n^n}\right)^{1/n}
=
\lim_ {n\to\infty}  \frac {3} {n}\
= 0
$$
Therefore, the series converges and so
$$
\lim_ {n\to\infty} \frac {3^n} {n^n} = 0
$$

Comment: Isn't that a bit overkill? ( I mean, most people do consider sequences before introducing series...)

Answer (score 0):

One with subsequences. Call $u_n = \left(\frac{3}{n}\right)^n$. Then $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = 3 \frac{n^n}{{(n+1)}^{n+1}} \le  3 \frac{n^n}{(n+1)n^n} $$
so at least after $n=3$ the sequence is decreasing. It is lower bounded by $0$, so converging, and it suffices to choose a nice subsequence to find the limit. To make things simple, try $n=3k$. Then
$$u_{3k} = k^{-3k}\,.$$
By taking the $\log$, you easily get that $-3k \log k \to -\infty $ as $k \to \infty$, hence the limit of the subsequence is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it as 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n \ln\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)}
$$
$$
n \ln \left(\frac{3}{n}\right) \to -\infty
$$
So
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n \ln \left(\frac{3}{n}\right)} = 0
$$